# Date comparison in python

Tags: python, pandas

i have already two datasets each one has 2 columns (date, close)
i want to compare date of the first dataset to the date of the second dataset if they are the same date the close of the second dataset takes the value relative to the date in question else it takes the value of the date of previous day.

This is the dataset https://www.euronext.com/fr/products/equities/FR0000120644-XPAR
https://fr.finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EFCHI/history?period1=852105600&period2=1528873200&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime , timedelta
import pandas as pd
#import cac 40 stock index (dataset1)
df = pd.read_csv('cac 40.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(df) 
#import Danone index(dataset2)
df1 = pd.read_excel('Price_Data_Danone.xlsx',header=3)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1) 
#check the number of observation of both datasets and get the minimum number
if len(df1)>len(df):
    size=len(df)
elif len(df1)<len(df):
     size=len(df1)
else:
     size=len(df)
#get new close values of dataset2 relative to the date in datset1
close1=np.zeros((size))
for i in range(0,size,1):
    # find the date of dataset1 in dataset 2
    if (df['Date'][i]in df1['Date']):
    #get the index of the date and the corresponding value of close and store it in close1
        close1[i]=df['close'][df1.loc['Date'][i], df['Date']]
    else:
        #if the date doesen't exist in datset2
    #take value of close of previous date of datatset1
        close1[i]=df['close'][df1.loc['Date'][i-1], df['Date']]
```

This is my trail, i got this error :
KeyError: 'the label [Date] is not in the [index]'
Examples:

we look for the value `df['Date'][1]` = '5/06/2009' in the column `df1['Date']`
we get its index in `df1['Date']`
then `close1=df1['close'][index]`
else if `df['Date'][1]` = '5/06/2009' not in `df1['Date']` 
we get the index of the previous date `df['Date'][0]` = '4/06/2009'
`close1=df1['close'][previous index]`

Comment: Could you maybe reformat the question to show example of input data and desired output?

Comment: Also which line is generating the error? I can see things I think would generate the error but without a few lines of the actual data I can't be sure.

Comment: I shared the links of data and i did an example above

Comment: In lines 6 and then 9, df = pd.DataFrame(df1) and df1 = pd.DataFrame(df). Don't you have error here already?

Comment: No, is not the error

Comment: Could you also provide direct links to download these datasets? I am not fluent in French and I can't get through these pages. Right click on download link and copy url, it'll make it easier to recreate.

Comment: @dylan_fan i updated the link you can click to Téléchargement or Télecharger les données

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error happens in line:

`close1[i]=df['close'][df1.loc['Date'][i], df['Date']]`

If your goal here is to get `close` value from `df` given `i` index you should write:

`close[i] = df['close'][i]`

See if that helps, unfortunately I don't understand fully what you are trying to accomplish, for example why do you set `size` to the length of shorter table?
Also, as long as I downloaded correct files, your condition `df['Date'][i]in df1['Date']` might not work, one date format uses `-` and the other `\`.

**Solution**

```
import pandas as pd


pd.set_option('expand_frame_repr', False)

# load both files
df = pd.read_csv('CAC.csv')
df1 = pd.read_csv('DANONE.csv', header=3)

# ensure date format is the same between two
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, dayfirst=True)
df1.Date = pd.to_datetime(df1.Date, dayfirst=True)

# you need only Date and Close columns as far as I understand
keep_columns = ['Date', 'Close']

# let's keep only these columns then
df = df[keep_columns]
df1 = df1[keep_columns]

# merge two tables on Date, method is left so that for every row in df we 
# 'append' row from df1 if possible, if not there will be NaN value, 
# for readability I added suffixes df - CAC and df1 - DANONE
merged = pd.merge(df,
                  df1,
                  on='Date',
                  how='left',
                  suffixes=['CAC', 'DANONE'])

# now for all missing values in CloseDANONE, so if there is Date in df
# but not in df1 we fill this value with LAST available
merged.CloseDANONE.fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)

# we get values from CloseDANONE column as long as it's not null
close1 = merged.loc[merged.CloseDANONE.notnull(), 'CloseDANONE'].values
```

Below you can see: 
last 6 values from df - CAC

```
           Date        Close
5522 2018-06-06  5457.560059
5523 2018-06-07  5448.359863
5524 2018-06-08  5450.220215
5525 2018-06-11  5473.910156
5526 2018-06-12  5453.370117
5527 2018-06-13  5468.240234
```

last 6 values from df1 - DANONE:

```
        Date  Close
0 2018-06-06  63.86
1 2018-06-07  63.71
2 2018-06-08  64.31
3 2018-06-11  64.91
4 2018-06-12  65.43
```

last 6 rows from merged:

```
           Date     CloseCAC  CloseDANONE
5522 2018-06-06  5457.560059        63.86
5523 2018-06-07  5448.359863        63.71
5524 2018-06-08  5450.220215        64.31
5525 2018-06-11  5473.910156        64.91
5526 2018-06-12  5453.370117        65.43
5527 2018-06-13  5468.240234        65.43
```

For every value that was present in `df` we get value from `df1`, but `2018-06-13` is not present in `df1` so I fill it with last available value which is `65.43` from `2018-06-12`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply i did change both date format to date in excel . yes i did compare the size to get the length of the shorter table But your answer didn't resolve my objective .

Comment: Do you have the same error still? Did you also edited else clause to close1[i] = df['close'][i-1]

Comment: Understood but it 's not necessary that df['Date'][i]==df1['Date'][i] it can be in another index even the dates are ordered but there are some missing date cuz of holidays

Comment: Well I just tried to fix that KeyError. What you try to do is: you iterate through dates in df, check if particular date is present in df1. If it is present then you save close value from this date from df1 in your close1 array, correct? And if date from df is not present in df1 then you'd like to save last available value from df1, correct?